# Error executing ant :-bash: ant: command not found

Tags: java, linux, bash, ant

I am trying to deploy my application in a Linux box, I have a file called setAppPath.sh file as:

```
#!/bin/sh
APP_HOME=`pwd`
ANT_HOME=$APP_HOME/lib/ant

echo $ANT_HOME

PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$APP_HOME/scripts/unix:$PATH

echo $PATH

chmod +x $ANT_HOME/bin/ant
chmod +x $APP_HOME/scripts/unix/*.sh

export APP_HOME ANT_HOME PATH
```

When I try to execute `ant` command I get an error message as:

```
-bash: ant: command not found
```

The echo `$ANT_HOME` is printing my ant home location the PATH is printed properly too.

After execting `setAppPath.sh` file I tried echo $ANT_HOME it gave empty line.

Please help me figuring out this issue.

**Edit 1:** `which ant` give no ant

I am using sh setAppPath.sh command to execute the sh file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your script normally, what happens is that your shell starts a new process, the script runs in that process, and when the script is done the process dies and control returns to your shell.

All modifications that the script did to its environment die with it. The changes have no effect on the parent shell. Same if you're trying to run `cd` in a script and expecting the parent shell to move.

To run your script in the context of your shell and not in a subprocess, use the `source` or `.` commands:

```
source setAppPath.sh
. setAppPath.sh
```

Comment: Thanks Mat for explaining.